# Transfer Money through Paypal Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal

I need to integrate the capability of transferring the money through paypal from one user to another via android mobile application. I had gone through `Paypal SDK` and documentation on their developer website but it is little bit confusing. So, can anyone help me out with how we can implement `Paypal SDK` for transferring money.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not supported by the SDK at the moment. It (and the REST APIs) only support the case where the merchant/developer accepts money from the end user.

Comment: Hi @tomwhipple, How can you say that do you have this written over somewhere or in documentation ?

Comment: I can say that because I'm the engineering lead for the SDKs. ;) I'll see about updating the docs.

Comment: Sorry,I got the Idea by seeing your profile. So can we do this by implementing paypal API on server side and interacting it through android mobile?